# Python CSV to Table in Email

Tags: python

I'm trying to send an html table in an email. I'm not sure if this is the best way or not, but right now I read in the CSV, create a table, and then email the info.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def create_table():
    print("<html><table>")
    # column headers
    print("<th>")
    print("<td>Tech</td>")
    print("<td>Total</td>")
    print("<td>Average</td>")
    print("</th>")

    infile = open("test.csv","r")

    for line in infile:
        row = line.split(",")
        tech = row[0]
        total = row[1]
        average = row[2]
        print("<td>%s</td>" % tech)
        print("<td>%s</td>" % total)
        print("<td>%s</td>" % average)

    print("</table></html>")

SERVER = "localhost"
FROM = "forsdani@amazon.com"
TO = ["forsdani@amazon.com"] # must be a list
SUBJECT = "this is my email"
TEXT = "TABLE GOES HERE?"

message = """\

From: %s
To: %s
Subject: %s

%s

""" % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)

# Send the mail
server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
server.quit()
```

If I do something like

```
TEXT = create_table()
```

then I get "None" for the text in the email. I'm not sure how to correct get the data from the function to the body of the email.

Comment: Are you trying to return the text printed in the function? A `return` statement would do that.

Comment: You need to build the table (say as a string, or list of strings) and return it from the function.

Comment: I see ``<td>``, but I see no ``<tr>``. Maybe get more familiar with HTML tables first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the function changed to return a value:

```
def create_table():
    message = ""
    message += "<html><table>" + "\n"
    # column headers
    message += "<th>" + "\n"
    message += "<td>Tech</td>" + "\n"
    message += "<td>Total</td>" + "\n"
    message += "<td>Average</td>" + "\n"
    message += "</th>" + "\n"

    infile = open("test.csv","r")

    for line in infile:
        row = line.split(",")
        tech = row[0]
        total = row[1]
        average = row[2]
        message += ("<td>%s</td>" % tech) + "\n"
        message += ("<td>%s</td>" % total) + "\n"
        message += ("<td>%s</td>" % average) + "\n"

    message += ("</table></html>") + "\n"
    return message
```

Comment: I was just trying to fix the function as is and give a framework for @dkeeper09 to use

Comment: thanks. and thanks for the <tr> callouts everyone. Dont know why I missed those :/

Answer (score 1):

Your function does not return any values, it only prints them.
Instead of something like:

```
def create_table():
    print("Hello, World!")
output = create_table() # output is None
```

Try:

```
def create_table():
    string_to_return = "Hello, World!"
    return string_to_return
output = create_table() # output is "Hello, World!"
```